# How do I set the environment in Heroku when running my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables, environment

I have a Rails 4.2.5 app that I just deployed to Heroku.  What I’m wondering is how do I set the environment that my Rails app runs in.  I want to set the environment to be test, but now it is getting set to development.  Per Heroku’s documentation, I created a file named “Procfile” at the root of my project and added this line to it

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-test}
```

but my app is still getting deployed in dev mode.  I know this because I set some environment variables via a file “./config/environment_variables.yml”, which looks like

```
development:
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: 425025269574-o5ejue1pgtsjoid0f0k8r7lcksfse6hk.apps.googleusercontent.com
  GOOGLE_SECRET: 16ckoTU_RbRKkdxv7_wkZnw8
  FACEBOOK_KEY: "6574234667329742"
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: 690e7faeb05199e5392892d397b79f8e
test:
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: 425025269574-gkcj8t19palgj34e5an4gj3mk68grpeg.apps.googleusercontent.com
  GOOGLE_SECRET: mokumLI9XdD8f10M6oamj7Jx
  FACEBOOK_KEY: "8877114738693318"
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: 779102b0e08e4374ca7c6986924bcf9b7
production:
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: 425025269574-gkcj8t19palgj34e5an4gj3mk68grpeg.apps.googleusercontent.com
  GOOGLE_SECRET: mokumLI9XdD8f10M6oamj7Jx
  FACEBOOK_KEY: "8877114738693318"
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: 779102b0e08e4374ca7c6986924bcf9b7
```

but only the development vars are getting set.

Comment: You're going to want to rotate all those application secrets you just posted to the internet.

Comment: Use 'em! Go ahead, bring down the app, I dare you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Profile to the following:

`web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

And set the `RAILS_ENV` to `test` as follows:

`heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=test`

If you have not modified your `config/puma.rb` then it should have the following:

`environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }`

which relies on `RAILS_ENV`, not `RACK_ENV`.

Answer (score 0):

for your procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

then reference your RACK_ENV var in your puma.rb file

RACK_ENV should be set to production in your heroku config. I believe it is by default but you could also set it. Check by running heroku config.

If it isn't set run:

```
 heroku config:set RACK_ENV=production
```

**EDIT**: you aren't actually trying to change the environment. Or you shouldn't be. Based on your comments you need to do this on the heroku server:

```
heroku config:set GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=425025269574-gkcj8t19palgj34e5an4gj3mk68grpeg.apps.googleusercontent.com GOOGLE_SECRET=mokumLI9XdD8f10M6oamj7Jx FACEBOOK_KEY="8877114738693318" FACEBOOK_SECRET=779102b0e08e4374ca7c6986924bcf9b7
```

Those are the credentials you've mistakenly labeled as test, because you're thinking of the server you set up for "testing" as a "test environment." That's not what Rails means when it references a test env. It means the environment for running your test locally. Just put those variables on heroku and allow it to be production.

Comment: What are the contents of your puma.rb file?

Comment: Hi, I added the puma.rb file as you specified in your post and ran "heroku config:set RACK_ENV=test", but alas I'm still getting heroku using the production settings instead of the test settings that I desire.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking...yeah production isn't going to be the test environment. The test environment is just for running your tests. Which you do locally, before you deploy. When you deploy, you're in production.

Comment: Your question makes it seem like your application is using development instead of production.

Comment: I should have phrased my question more generally -- is tehre any way to chnage the heroku environment from production to something else?  If so, how?

Comment: Confused as to why would you not want production to be production? Production is production. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If production is production then why did you put "heroku config:set RACK_ENV=production" in your answer?  By your logic, it should always be production, so why would you need to specify it in an environment variable like RACK_ENV?

Comment: I'm trying to help you but you won't tell me what you're trying to do. No desire to argue. Feel free to ignore all of this. I just can't think of a scenario where you'd want to tell production not to use production.

Comment: I appreciate your help and would be even more grateful if you just told me the answer.  We are using the heroku (free) service for our testing environment.  Production will live elsewhere.  Development is my local environment.  Ok ... now its your turn to answer my questions.

Comment: Ah--you don't actually mean testing the way rails means it. You mean staging. And staging is production. Testing is the environment that gets spun up locally so you can run your test suite. Staging is a production server where things can be manually tested before they go to the real production server. A staging server will still show as a production environment...but you can set any ENV variables you want on that server and it will use those.

Comment: Just add those credentials you've mistakenly labeled as 'test' and add them to the heroku config by running heroku config:set

Comment: No dice.  As I said, I ran "heroku config:set RACK_ENV=test" in addition to everything else you specified in your post but the environment is still treated as production.

Comment: yeah--that's not what I meant---I meant set the environment variables you want using that (ie: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and others). you literally can't tell production to be test. And what you're talking about ISN'T TEST! It's a staging server. Test refers to the environment you use to run your test locally. I don't know how else to explain that but it's clearly not being received.